# Styling two divs on a row

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am building a website: http://akce.region-tour.cz/ahoj-vsichni/

If you scroll down, you will see 4 boxes (pictures with a link above). Every image is on a different row now. What I want to do is to style It, so there are two rows and each row has two boxes (see picture)

[THIS IS HOW I WANT IT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3aWI.png)

```html
 <div style="width: 400px;"><a href="www.region-tour.cz/krkonose">Krkonoše</a><img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-131" src="http://akce.region-tour.cz/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/krkonose.jpg" alt="Krkonoše" width="400" height="150" /></div>

<div style="width: 400px;"><a href="http://www.region-tour.cz/ubytovani-ceske-svycarsko/ubytovani-luzicke-hory/">Lužické hory</a><img class="size-full wp-image-132 alignleft" src="http://akce.region-tour.cz/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/luzicke-hory.jpg" alt="Lužické hory" width="400" height="150" /></div>

<div style="width: 400px;"><a href="www.region-tour.cz/orlicke-hory">Krkonoše</a><img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-133" src="http://akce.region-tour.cz/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/orlicke-hory.jpg" alt="orlické hory" width="400" height="150" /></div>

<div style="width: 400px;"><a href="www.region-tour.cz/jizeske-hory">Jizerské hory</a><img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-130" src="http://akce.region-tour.cz/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/jizerky.jpg" alt="Jizerské hory" width="400" height="150" /></div>
```

Comment: use bootstrap class "col-md-6" for each div

Comment: @PadmaRubhan i am not using bootstrap

Comment: please do not use bootstrap

Comment: @pajicekkralicek, you want something like this? https://ibb.co/b62wBk

Comment: At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would make two rows, and each row has a right and left div

```css
    .row {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    margin:1em 0;
    }
    .row .left {
    width:48%;
    float:left;
    }
    .row .right {
    width:48%;
    float:right;
    }
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="left">img here</div>
    <div class="right">img here</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="left">img here</div>
    <div class="right">img here</div>
    </div>
```

my above example is clean html and css and fully responsive.

Comment: Only one problem now, if i add the links before the image inside div, they are not showed all. Example: <a href="">Krkonoše</a> shows "noše" @HollerTrain

Comment: pick up a jsfillde account and show me there. you will need to add some styling block to the a link inside each`.row` of course.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous solutions and @HollerTrain provides a clean one. Here is a different solution using CSS3 flexbox which I find to be an excellent construct for providing flexible layouts.

CSS

```
.flex-container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 850px;
}

.flex-container div {
    width: 400px;
    height: 160px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="flex-container">
<div style="width: 400px;"><a href="www.region-tour.cz/krkonose">Krkonoše</a><img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-131" src="http://akce.region-tour.cz/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/krkonose.jpg" alt="Krkonoše" width="400" height="150" /></div>

<div style="width: 400px;"><a href="http://www.region-tour.cz/ubytovani-ceske-svycarsko/ubytovani-luzicke-hory/">Lužické hory</a><img class="size-full wp-image-132 alignleft" src="http://akce.region-tour.cz/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/luzicke-hory.jpg" alt="Lužické hory" width="400" height="150" /></div>

<div style="width: 400px;"><a href="www.region-tour.cz/orlicke-hory">Krkonoše</a><img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-133" src="http://akce.region-tour.cz/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/orlicke-hory.jpg" alt="orlické hory" width="400" height="150" /></div>

<div style="width: 400px;"><a href="www.region-tour.cz/jizeske-hory">Jizerské hory</a><img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-130" src="http://akce.region-tour.cz/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/jizerky.jpg" alt="Jizerské hory" width="400" height="150" /></div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jfeferman/h04mfkga/1/)

Comment: You can definitely make it responsive by using a percentage based width on flex-container such as 100% or 100vw of the viewport. Blocks will wrap depending on available space.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>

  .row{
   width:100%;
   float:left;
   margin:0 auto;
  }

  .colum1{
   width:48%;
   float:left;
   margin:0 auto;
  }

  .colum2{
   width:48%;
   float:right;
   margin:0 auto;
  }

  .colum3{
   width:48%;
   float:left;
   margin:0 auto;
  }

  .colum4{
   width:48%;
   float:right;
   margin:0 auto;
  }

</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="colum1">
           content here..
        </div>
        <div class="colum2">
           content here..
        </div>
        <div class="colum3">
           content here..
        </div>
        <div class="colum4">
           content here..
        </div>
    </div><!-- ./row -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: your duplicate css declarations for a column is really disturbing.